# Animation bug. Using godot game engine

Tags: godot, gdscript

I am working on a game and for some reason when I try to call the hit_check() function it won't animate the sprite. all of the other animations have worked perfectly which is why I'm confused.
Heres my script:

```
extends KinematicBody2D

var motion = Vector2(0,0)

const SPEED = 130
const GRAVITY = 15
const UP = Vector2(0,-1)
const JUMP_SPEED = 350

func _physics_process(delta):
    apply_gravity()
    hit_check()
    jump_check()
    move_check()
    move_and_slide(motion, UP)
    
func apply_gravity():
    if not is_on_floor():
        motion.y += GRAVITY
    else:
        motion.y = 0
    
    
func jump_check():
    if Input.is_action_pressed("jump") and is_on_floor():
        motion.y -= JUMP_SPEED
    
    
func move_check():
    if Input.is_action_pressed('left'):
        $PlayerAnimation.flip_h = true
        $PlayerAnimation.play("walk")
        motion.x = -SPEED
    elif Input.is_action_pressed('right'):
        $PlayerAnimation.flip_h = false
        $PlayerAnimation.play("walk")
        motion.x = SPEED
    else:
        motion.x = 0
        $PlayerAnimation.play("idle")


func hit_check():
    if Input.is_action_pressed("hit"):
        $PlayerAnimation.play("hit")
```

Comment: Are you sure the hit action occurs?  Add a `print` statement in `hit_check()` before the animation.

Answer (score 0):

*jump_check* and *move_check* functions are called **after** *hit_check* function, and *move_check* function **always** overrides the current animation of the node because there is an animation specified in both if and else blocks.